# Clean way to append to a list in a recursive function

Tags: python

When finding permutations for a list like this:

```
def permut(nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
    result = []

    def perm(a, k=0):
        if k == len(a):
            result.append(a)
        else:
            for i in range(k, len(a)):
                a[k], a[i] = a[i], a[k]
                perm(a, k + 1)
                a[k], a[i] = a[i], a[k]

    perm(nums)
    return result
```

this doesn't work because I'm overwriting `a` each time and result is just a list of items all pointing to `a`

I can change that line to be like:

```
result.append([item for item in a])
```

But that seems just like a hack to create a new list from a. What is a better way to deal with append to list in recursive functions?

Comment: Maybe ```result.append(list(a))```.

Comment: For this particular case, do you know about `itertools`?

Comment: That isn't a "hack", that's what you have to do if you want to append a copy of that list instead of that same list object. Of course, `[item for item in a]` is a verbose way of writing `list(a)`, although if `a` is a list, perhaps the most readable (and performant) way would simply be `a.copy()`

Comment: You can also use `result.append(a[:])`

Comment: ok, I thought there is something wrong with my algorithm that I had to arrive to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better recursive approach is to avoid managing the item swapping back-and-forth yourself and instead rely on the call stack to do that for you:

```
def perm(lst):
    if lst:
        for index, item in enumerate(lst):
            for p in perm(lst[:index] + lst[index + 1:]):
                yield [item, *p]
    else:
        yield []
```

so that:

```
for p in perm([1, 2, 3]):
    print(p)
```

outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
```